# Connect Tableau server to excel file on OneDrive

Tags: excel, onedrive, tableau-desktop

I have an excel file on my personal OneDrive that is updated weekly manually.

I created a tableau dashboard which is connected to this excel file, and I shared the dashboard on Tableau server.

But it seems that in tableau server the weekly updates are not taken.

Could you help me please to fix this problem thank you.

Comment: Is the data source in Server set to Extract or Live?

Comment: It's an extract. It's An .xlsx file saved on my OneDrive.

Comment: If it's an extract, did you schedule a refresh?  If yes, then check Server UI to verify there are no errors when the extract refresh runs.